# Create aws lambda function with dynamic path

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I'm creating an aws lambda function using VS Code aws plugin, the language is nodeJS.

I need to pass a dynamic id in the request preferably as part of the path.

In nodeJS express I would do it something like this

```
/api/route/:id
```

However when I try to do this in my lambda function's `template.yaml` like this

```
Events:
    HelloWorld:
      Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
      Properties:
      //***** this line
        Path: /api/route/:id
        Method: get
```

It does'n work

Any help would be appreciated

P.S. I'm able to pass it as a query param like so

```
https://awslambdafunction.com/api/route/?id=1234
```

It does work but I would really  like to have it as part of the path itself like this

```
https://awslambdafunction.com/api/route/1234
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shmili,

I'm not sure if it'll work with AWS VS Code plugin. But I did it like this using Serverless Framework:

```
functions:
  updateBook:
    handler: handler.updateBook
    events:
      - http:
          path: /book/{id}
          method: put
          private: true
```

It may put you on a right direction.